# Error Accesing to container on Bluemix

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

From my Bluemix Dashboard if I try to acces to the container tabs to list or create any container I obtain an error like this capture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UInqs.png)

If a logon to my Bluemix account from shell (Ubuntu 12.04)
and execute this:

`cf ic login`

I obtain this error:

```
"description": "Not authorized: {
   "code": "IC5017E", 
   "description": "The ID could not be validated. Log in to the CLI again.", 
   "incident_id": "2364-1472136150.189-27574423", 
   "name": "Token", 
   "rc": "500", 
   "type": "Authorization"
}
```

I logon from my shell to other account in Bluemix and everything is ok, list the docker images, pull an image to my local repository to create a container, so the SO, and the cli are correct installed, the problem is with this account, but What?, I don't have any container created in Bluemix now in this problematic account

Answer (score 0):

How many spaces do you have in your organization? Make sure you have enough resource or quota on your 'cf login' target org/space. You can check it on your 'Organization Management' Menu.

And have you tried to use "cf ic init"?

Comment: Yes I execute the command with this error:

Deleting old configuration file...
Retrieving client certificates for IBM Containers...
{
    "code": "IC5099E", 
    "description": "Not authorized: {\n    \"code\": \"IC5017E\", \n    \"description\": \"The ID could not be validated. Log in to the CLI again.\", \n    \"incident_id\": \"1914-1472553991.866-26807068\", \n    \"name\": \"Token\", \n    \"rc\": \"500\", \n    \"type\": \"Authorization\"\n}", 
    "incident_id": "1914-1472553991.866-26807068", 
    "name": "NotAuthorized", 
    "rc": "401", 
    "type": "Infrastructure"
}

Comment: Then you may need to try cf login to your different space, with the cf ic login after you cf login successful. To see if it works on other spaces in your org.